# Inexpensive online tool for creating a survey

Tags: web-apps, survey

I want to create a survey to gather information on a medium-sized population (a hundred of people). I have many questions to ask them.

I am looking for an online tool to achieve this task. I have seen websites such as [SurveyMonkey](https://www.surveymonkey.com) but their pricing is much too high for me.

**What are the inexpensive and best online tools for creating surveys?**

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! We will need much more information to give good recommendations here – asking for "a tool like X" is never giving enough details, even if linked. You should always list your requirements explicitly. Please see [How to ask for an alternative to some software](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/48/185) and the questions linked to it for details.

Comment: What's your budget, what are you willing to pay for such a service/program? And is it just this one survey you want to conduct, or will you be conducting more surveys in the future? (if yes, will it be for the same audience?)

Comment: I might conduct several surveys, for the same audience, but not more than 3. I don't really have a budget. I have been advised to use  google form and http://www.typeform.com.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Google Forms

http://www.google.com/forms/about/?gclid=CjwKEAjwgcipBRDgxK_3ztrBty8SJACRuv4dfhZ4ysDRTqO8M67i1QhO8sMJrkPOnfFaWI7EzxOO6xoCtcvw_wcB

It is the best tool what you are looking for
Some awesome features of Google Forms:

- Unlimited surveys
- Add your own custom logo
- 100% free!
- Imbed survey into emails or website.

  Google Forms is the only free online survey tool that provides free skip logic, which is pretty awesome. This will probably be the first pick for most.

Below given link will show you the best 7 tools regarding survey task.  Survey monkey is also there, but you can skip this as it is not your requirement. These tools providing some features in their free-demo version, you can check this easily but some software’s are paid also.

http://www.wordstream.com/blog/ws/2014/11/10/best-online-survey-tools

Comment: Nice answer! Note there still is [Adobe Forms Central](https://www.acrobat.com/de_de/landing/formscentral-eol.html?lang=en) I have successfully used before. But I just found out it will go offline by the 28th of July. Until the 22nd of June you can still use it fully.

Answer (score 0):

**Disclosure: I work for PollUnit.**

You can do this with a [PollUnit survey](https://pollunit.com/en/survey). All input types are available in the free plan. You can create as many surveys as you like. But you need a paid plan if you want more than 40 participants per survey. The plans are starting at 4 USD per month.

Here are some example survey steps:

[image: screenshots of survey examples]